# Copying from Excel to Word with tabs and linebreaks

Tags: excel, ms-word, tabs, newline

I'm trying to copy cells from Excel to Word. I have a cell with a value like this:

> (data1)ttt(data2)#(data3)

After pasting, I replace ttt with ^t and # with ^p. I tried writing ^t and ^p instead of my current delimiters, but it didn't work. Is there a way to do it while copying from a single cell?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't specify what language you are using, and the mention of `^t` and `^p` makes me think this **isn't** VBA but, just in case it **is** VBA, wouldn't it be simpler to replace `"ttt"` with `vbTab` and `"#"` with `vbNewLine`?

Comment: well, I'm not using any languages. This is plain Excel, and data is put together using formulas. Then I ctrl-c in excel and ctrl-v in word. Then I find and replace those delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

When you find and replace in word, after clicking ^H, that will activate Find and Replace window. Enter ttt in find text box and click on 'More' button, in the find and replace window, then select "Tab Character" from the "special" button found at the bottom. Then click on "Replace All" Button. The same way you select either "Manual line break" or 'Paragraph Mar' from 'Special' button for line break and then 'Replace All' Button..